# Strange files Appearing in my project folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, drive

After saving my project, and restart the PC (or shutdown then boot later) some strange files appearing in my project folders, also my project not being saved (specially designer)

Plus, these strange files with random extension (can be opened using Notepad) and my codes of my projects there (I can get back my saved codes by opening these strange files and copy paste). But I need to put new controllers in project designer, again and again.

I am using Shadow Defender (my C drive is on shadow mode) but project folders are in except list.

These are the files:

[image]

After opening the project (with having strange files) this error comes too in end of my codes:

[image]

### Edit

Somehow, I get my project back (but not last saved one) after designer not showing and throwing error.

When I open my project, a folder (random name) show up in C drive with files like these: storage.ide-shm + storage.ide-wal + storage.ide + db.lock in folder name sqlite3, I believe these files should be in .vs folder in project, and I can't delete this folder while my project is open.

Comment: It sounds like this is an effect of this "Shadow Defender" product and not Visual Studio or Visual Basic.  You may want to contact that vendor's support.

Comment: does vb project use some sort of temp folder to safe project ? ( or just project folder is enough ) i know its stupid and newbie question, because i am just making my project folder as an exclusive from being SHADOWED.. also this happened for one of my project only, then now today started to another project too

Comment: Visual Studio (*not* Visual Basic, it's an important difference) might make use of the host OS's temp storage capabilities. It's a very large and complex application.  But overall if you've installed some 3rd party tool which specifically prevents writing to existing files, presumably it writes to *something* in order to save data. It seems reasonable that these strange files are that something. It's possible the product has limitations that Visual Studio is reaching, or that it's misconfigured in some way, or that it's not a good product. Either way, it looks unrelated to Visual Studio.

Comment: when i open my project a folder shown in C drive with random name and inside a folder sqlite3 with theses files: storage.ide-shm + storage.ide-wal + storage.ide + db.lock, i cant delete them while project is open, and i think these files should be  in .vs hidden folder in project, but why its in C drive ? and what these files does ?? does it like store some data of changes in project and etc ? that why my 3rd party preventing any changes on whole C os ? that issue was not happening before neither happened with vb 2008, its just 2019 issue, in my vs folder only one file with .suo extension

Answer (score 0):

well, its turn out i have to use COMMIT option of shadow defender, for some reason using file exception in SD, damaging the projects which producing some other fiels in C drive..